# Missing A Figure

Tags: lateral-thinking

Out of all the elements of a **specific** set, a subset of 7 elements have a special property. Your job is to replace the question mark so that the list below becomes complete.

---

[image]

Comment: I thought that sets always contain different elements and cannot contain the same element (e.g. {circle, circle}) is this wrong?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Yes that's right, but i was refering to the rot13(yngva nycunorg nf gur frg, naq gur fhofrg nf gur yrggref jvgu "ubyrf" va gurz.). I'll edit the last sentence.

Comment: It’s good that you changed the wording since in the original way it was stated you made it seem that the set of shapes somehow = the set of letters that is why I didn’t put the actual answer initially even though I did think of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> **TRIANGLE**

Since

> All these clues point to the subset of the **7 only letters which **enclose a space in capitals**** in the set of the Modern Latin Alphabet. The clues also belong to a set where each member is the shape or shapes belonging to each of such letter.

> All these clues represent these letters by virtue of describing **the shape or shapes which these letters have that enclose a region**. And from the top down the list of clues **matches these letters** if such letters were arranged in order of which they appear in the alphabetic sequence in a top down manner (starting from B):

> B(two ellipses)

> D(semi-circle)

> O(circle)

> P(half-ellipse)

> Q(circle)

> R(half-ellipse)

> These therefore represent 6/7 letters and the last 6 letters of the sequence of these letters are ordered alphabetically. **In that sequence top down!**

Therefore

> Since then the ? being on the top of the list is denoting the missing shape or shapes (out of that set) which encloses a region belonging to the missing first letter of the sequence and the letter missing is the first term in the sequence of letters which is the **LETTER A**. The answer must be a **TRIANGLE**.

Title

> Hints at a triangle since it is a **three sided *figure***! Also as I wrote before but I deleted it: title also refers to the letter A in caps.

Comment: so the answer is: TRIANGLE

Comment: Well done! The alternative is the intended answer (GEVNATYR)

Comment: The title clue is even more direct than that :^)

Comment: I don’t know why I deleted that the title hint as I had it in before and it was a a good find Axiomatic system 

Answer (score 7):

I think that this is

> about the digits from 0-9 (specific set). The special property that the subset of 7 elements has is a curved segment when writing that digit.
>  The description in the question is referring to the shape of the curved segment in that digit. Particularly, the ones that belong to this subset are:
>  **0**: **CIRCLE**
>  **2**: **HALF ELLIPSE** 
>  **3**: **TWO HALF ELLIPSES** 
>  **5**: **HALF ELLIPSE** 
>  **6**: **CIRCLE** 
>  **9**: **SEMI-CIRCLE** (for this one, maybe it is because 9 is usually drawn with a semi-circle followed by a line, so it ends up being a semicircle)
>  So, the missing number is **8**, which has **TWO CIRCLES**.
>  The "Figure" in the title is probably a reference to the [Figure-of-eight Knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-eight_knot)

Comment: I'm convinced. But what about the title of the puzzle?

Comment: @codewarrior0 Added an explanation for the title.

Comment: Nice attempt! But this isn't the intended solution.

Comment: @Prim3numbah oh wow. I was quite sure of this haha. Back to the drawing board, I guess...